# hide table columns automatically by checking a checkbox with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to display 3 checkboxes that are pre-checked, but as soon as the user unchecks a box, the related column disappears.

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="first_name" checked> First Name</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="last_name" checked> Last Name</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="email" checked> Email</p>
```

Rendered html of the table

```
<table id="report>
<thead>
<tr>
 <th class="first_name">First Name</th>
 <th class="last_name">Last Name</th>
 <th class="email">Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td class="first_name">Larry</td>
 <td class="last_name">Hughes</td>
 <td class="email">larry@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="first_name">Mike</td>
 <td class="last_name">Tyson</td>
 <td class="email">mike@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I imagine it will have to do with a live click event, setting the each class to .hide()

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455699/show-hide-table-column-with-colspan-using-jquery for answer with colspan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have columns hidden automatically for checkboxes that are hidden by default (page load), use the following code along with the click element to toggle the columns:

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).hide();
});

$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
    $(column).toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/highwayoflife/8BahZ/4/

This example also uses a selector like: $('table .class_name'); which will be a faster selector if you are using the code on a larger page since it won't have to search through every DOM element to find the class names, it only looks under tables.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
      var column = "."+$(this).attr("name");
      $(column).toggle();
});
```

**UPDATE**

Check out the online demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/8BahZ/

Comment: Great example! -- Had a few HTML errors, however. http://jsfiddle.net/highwayoflife/8BahZ/1/

Comment: works great. what if I wanted to have a box that is unchecked by default, but it needs to hide the corresponding column until it has be checked by the user.

Comment: It did not. I removed "checked" from one of the checkboxes and it did not work here http://jsfiddle.net/8BahZ/

Comment: @highway of life, thanks for pointing that out. @Brad hhmm weird, it did for me, once one is checked the corresponding column has to disappear right? check here one last time: http://jsfiddle.net/8BahZ/3/

Comment: I want 2 out of the 3 checked by default. If the checkbox is checked, display the column, if it is not checked, do not display the column. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: I accepted the other answer as the correct one, but yours was correct, but I apologize for throwing a curve ball into the mix after you answered it originally, about the unchecked checkboxes